# Wpf- Unable to cast MenuItem to Listbox?

Tags: wpf, exception, xaml

I am getting a very strange exception. 
I get the exception:

`"'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '26' and line position '34'."`

When I look at the Inner Exception I get:

`"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox'."`

I have narrowed the cause of the exception to the `MenuItem` in the TreeViewItem style contained in this `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="ProjectElementTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectElementCollection}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Padding="0" SelectedItemChanged="ProjectElementTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" GotKeyboardFocus="ProjectElementTreeView_GotKeyboardFocus">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Name="AddProjectElementMenuItem" Header="Add" Click="AddProjectElementMenuItem_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

The exception only occurs when the `MenuItem` has a click event handler and is thrown even when the click event handler does not contain any code.

Comment: wow, that's *really* weird...

Comment: The code posted worked fine for me so I think your problem is in a different piece of code. What tries to set the ConnectionId?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the same exception as you did. After looking closer at the code, this feels like a situation where you would get

> "The event 'Click' cannot be specified
>   on a Target tag in a Style. Use an
>   EventSetter instead."

I'm not sure why that doesn't apply here.
Anyway, using an EventSetter works

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="AddProjectElementMenuItem" Header="Add">
                <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="AddProjectElementMenuItem_Click"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to face this weird situation myself. 
There is an easy way to get over it, you have to clean and rebuild the project and the exception will go away.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to go one further than this and close VS and delete the `obj` and the `bin` directories in the project folder.

Comment: None of this worked for me, ended up having to use the event setter.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code and it works for me.  Are you sure the code you posted is causing the problem?

Instead of placing the MenuItem in the content of ContextMenu, nest it under ContextMenu.Items:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem Name="AddProjectElementMenuItem"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>a
```

Comment: Still causes the exception. Once again, the exception only occurs when the MenuItem has a click event attached.

Comment: Yes, I did test it with the event handler attached.  I don't think there's anything wrong with the xaml you posted - it must be a machine/configuration problem.

Comment: What versions are you (both) using to try this.  [Disclaimer: I did not try this out myself - just trying to make sure you are comparing oranges to oranges.]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error and found out that I put the tagging outside `<MyApp:AppPage.Resources></MyApp:AppPage.Resources>`, i mean I know it has to be inside it but I did not notice that the closing tag was already called before my context menu tag. I thought I was still inside it. I just moved it before the closing tag and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Fredrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490996/43534) explains what's actually causing this, I think.  But here's an alternate solution.

You can also work around the problem by declaring the `ContextMenu` as a separate resource outside of the `Style`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="ProjectElementTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectElementCollection}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Padding="0" SelectedItemChanged="ProjectElementTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" GotKeyboardFocus="ProjectElementTreeView_GotKeyboardFocus">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu">
            <MenuItem Name="AddProjectElementMenuItem" Header="Add"
                      Click="AddProjectElementMenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Menu}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```