# Connect handler to ContextMenu in "Style" section

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, handler

I need to create structure of `ContextMenu` in runtime, because existence of `MenuItem`'s of the menu is based on many factors. And I try add handler to `ContextMenuOpening` event this way:

XAML

```
<TreeView x:Name="ArticlesTreeView" Grid.Column="0" AllowDrop="True">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_OnOpened">
                        <MenuItem Header="First item"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

This code throws `XamlParseException` on `<ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_OnOpened">` line. Can I solve issue in another way?

**UPD** I find that to me it is necessary not `ContextMenuOpening` and `Opened` event. I corrected upper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485355/wpf-unable-to-cast-menuitem-to-listbox).

Placing event handlers in event setter did the work.

```
<TreeView x:Name="ArticlesTreeView"  AllowDrop="True">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="First item">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening_1"></EventSetter>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeViewItem>

        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Also change your code behind event handler as

```
  private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating your ContextMenu on your ItemTemplate of the treeview. Try the below code (it is not complete but i hope you get the idea)

```
<TreeView .....>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ContentControl>
<ContentControl.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_OnContextMenuOpening">
                        <MenuItem Header="First item"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
</ContentControl.ContextMenu>
---------Your Item Template here
</ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, but I find that I need another event (in another object) and already find solution.